# Java Wait until threads(Threadpool) finish their work and start another work

Tags: java, multithreading

So I create lets say 5 threads, and after their work is completed I'd like to do another work.  so how to find out when threads from executor finish their work, and only then start superwork method?

Main:

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
   CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(5);//thread number
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

   getLogFile n = new getLogFile(doneSignal, i);// work method

   executor.execute(n);
   doneSignal.await();  
   }
```

//Probably here something like executor.awaitTermination(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);{doesn't work} or something that works

```
Superworkmethod(uses thread created files);//main thread probably starts thi
```

Class:

```
public static class getLogFile implements Runnable {
 private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
   private final int i;
   getLogFile(CountDownLatch doneSignal, int i) {
      this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
      this.i = i;
   }

    public int run1(String Filenamet) {
    //do work
    }
    public void run() {
            run1(file);
            doneSignal.countDown();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ExecutorService.invokeAll()`:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();    
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    tasks.add(Executors.callable(new getLogFile(doneSignal, i)));
}

executor.invokeAll(tasks);
// Here tasks are completed
```

Comment: does: tasks.add(Executors.callable(new getLogFile(doneSignal, i)); excecute each thread at a time or all threads at the same time? , bejause j2ssh connection that im using is executing one task/sends one command to server at the time

Comment: @user615927: `invokeAll()` executes tasks concurrently. If you want to execute them consequently, why do you need thread pool at all?

Comment: I guess I wanted to make something way more complicated than it should be(High level stuff-> works faster), ended the same way as always), also thought that using this would increase performance(many little tasks executed separatelly at same time ->speed)... anyway maybe u know how to stop main thread until other threads finish their work?